# How can I properly execute a command with lists using `sh -c`?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, sh

I have this command to recursively find directories that contain `mustExist.js` but not `cannotExist.js`:

```
comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)
```

It works fine.

Now, I must pass it as a string to a `node.js` automation script. The script picks up the string and runs it as `sh -c <string>`. I cannot change that part.

So I pass this string:

```
'comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \\; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \\; | sort -u)'
```

However, I always encounter this error:

```
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

When I pass this string:

```
'"comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \\; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \\; | sort -u)"'
```

I get:

```
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c "comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)"
/bin/sh: 1: comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u): not found
```

When I manually try using `sh` to immitate the automation script:

```
sh -c comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)
```

I get a different error:

```
comm: missing operand
```

Or with quotes:

```
sh -c "comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)"
```

I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Other quotes:

```
sh -c 'comm -13 <(find . -type f -name cannotExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u) <(find . -type f -name mustExist.js -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u)'

/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: "If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible," (source: man bash) . And sh does not have many features of bash, I think that the command result expansion is one of them. Possible workaround: put your command in a file, say my_find.sh, and run it with `sh -c "bash -c my_find.sh"`

Comment: Thank you @marekjancuska you must be right. That list format is not valid in `sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler and more efficient command you can use:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1"/mustExist.js && ! test -e "$1"/cannotExist.js' _ {} \; -print
```

This iterates over the directories, and checks each one for the required file as well as making sure the forbidden file is *not* present.

An example, where only `foo/bar3` contains `yes.js` without also containing `no.js`.

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar1 foo/bar2 foo/bar3
$ touch foo/bar1/no.js foo/bar1/yes.js foo/bar2/no.js foo/bar3/yes.js
$ find foo -type d -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1"/yes.js && ! test -e "$1"/no.js' _ {} \; -print
foo/bar3
```

Passing *this* to your script requires some creative quoting, though:

```
somescript "find foo -type d -exec sh -c 'test -e \"\$1\"/yes.js && ! test -e \"\$1\"/no.js' _ {} \; -print"
```

If you are using `bash`, you can simplify it a little:

```
somescript $'find foo -type d -exec sh -c \'test -e "$1"/yes.js && ! test -e "$1"/no.js\' _ {} \; -print'
```

---

If you are willing to use the obsolete and possibly unsupported operator `-a`, you can reduce this to a single invocation of `test`.

```
find . -type d -exec test -e {}/mustExist.js -a ! -e {}/cannotExist.js \; -print
```

This is also a little simpler to pass to your script, since it does not itself contain any quotes:

```
somescript 'find . -type d -exec test -e {}/mustExist.js -a ! -e {}/cannotExist.js \; -print'
```

---

You can simplify it using multiple `-exec` primaries as well:

```
somescript 'find . -type d -exec test -e {}/mustExist.js \; ! -exec test -e {}/cannotExist.js \; -print'
```

which is a little less efficient (it runs `test` twice instead of once) but is more portable, while being easier to quote than the version that passes the string to `sh -c`.

Comment: This is actually pretty nice! That first one executing `sh` is a bit tricky, the command itself is executed by `sh` and I need to forward the output to `sh` (not in the question) so that would be a nasty escaping job. However, your last command is awesome. I didn't know the `-exec`s could be chained like that. This solved my problems so I want to mark this as accepted answer, but it's technically not the answer to my specific question. I'm hoping the StackOverflow-police won't punish me for that.